# Issue with using complexplot with Nearest

Tags: plotting, complex, nearest

I have been trying to create a certain  fractal with Mathematica but the main issue is that if I try and do something like

```
ComplexPlot[
  Nearest[{I, -2 + I, 3 - 2 I}, z], 
  {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}
]
```

and then try to graph it, I keep getting these error messages:

> Nearest::neard: The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair z and I.
> Nearest::neard  The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair System`ComplexPlotsDump`nz$. and I.
> General::stop: Further output of Nearest::neard will be suppressed during this calculation.

I have tried doing this with normal plot and real numbers, which works just fine, and I know that nearest can handle complex numbers as it can do things like `Nearest[{I + 2, 3I}, 0]` and will output `2 + I`. So the issue is something with `ComplexPlot`. The final image given is also just a red square, which is unexpected. Anyone know how to help?

Comment: Perhaps an indirect approach might succeed: `nf = Nearest[{I, -2 + I, 3 - 2 I}]; nfx[z_?NumericQ] := nf[z]` and then try using `nfx[z]` instead in your plot.

Comment: @J.M. I tried that and the errors are no longer showing up but the output it still a large red box, which shouldn't be showing up

Comment: Ah, if you tried evaluating `nfx[]` at some arbitrary argument, you'd find that it gives a list and not a number. Perhaps `nfx[z_?NumericQ] := First[nf[z]]` is what you wanted instead?

Comment: @J.M. that works, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[ne]
ne[z_?NumericQ] := Nearest[{I, -2 + I, 3 - 2 I}, z][[1]]
ComplexPlot[ne[z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}]
```

[image]